Remove background realtime in React Native using Expo Camera
I am trying to simulate the behavior of applications like TikTok or Microsoft Teams that access the front camera of the phone and are able to remove the background in real time. In the case of TikTok it is even able to record and save the video.
I was looking at using Tensorflow but I have not been able to do anything satisfactory with React Native and Expo camera.
Can anyone help?
